# rails email preview / Policy directive: "style-src 'unsafe-inline'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, preview

Getting the following when using rails built in email previews :

```
    Refused to load the stylesheet
   'http://app.lvh.me:3000/packs/...' because it violates
    the following Content Security
    Policy directive: "style-src 'unsafe-inline'".
```

Ended up adding the following in headers :

```
meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
     content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';"
```

But still getting the issue

Does anyone encountered and solved this issue ?

Comment: Can you show the code of what is in your mailer?

Comment: Turned out we had to use an extra gem for this, as described here https://hackernotes.io/a-production-ready-rails-5-email-workflow-with-mailer-previews-premailer-and-activejob/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, this answer could be enhanced by explaining why such happened,
but so far it seems that the workaround is to add the following gem :

```
gem 'premailer-rails'
```

[As explained here.](https://hackernotes.io/a-production-ready-rails-5-email-workflow-with-mailer-previews-premailer-and-activejob/)

Comment: As of Rails 5.2, I get this issue even with this gem unfortunately.

Comment: See the link provided in the comment above (on hackernotes), it does work

Comment: It doesn't work for me because of this bug: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33483

Comment: Reading your issue; it crashes due to specific middlewares you're using ? Or does it fails by default ? We're on 5.2

Comment: I think your answer works for the op's question. My issue was similar in that CSP was blocking middleware javascript due to the script_source. If you don't otherwise have use for the premailer gem, you can instead monkeypatch Rails to fix the bug mentioned in the PR I referenced.

Comment: module MonkeyPatches
      require "rails/application_controller"
      class Rails::MailersController < 
    Rails::ApplicationController
        content_security_policy(false)
      end
    end

Comment: ok i see; so basically the monkey patch you're showing saves one from using this another gem ?

Comment: Right, in your and the OP's case. If you don't otherwise need that gem, you can remove it and add this monkey patch.